# SQL Azure Database Management Console vs Local SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure

Could someone please explain why the EXACT same call to run a stored procedure takes about 25 seconds to complete when run from my local SQL Server Management Studio but only takes 5 seconds (this is the time I'd expect it to take) when run from a query window in the "Manage" facility, inside the Azure portal? It's completely consistent no matter how many times I do it!

It's also running slow from our cloud application, which makes me think there's some kind of difference between "internal" and "external" access to the DB server.

Thanks.

Comment: And is your cloud application also in the Azure? Have you tried to check query->include client statistics when running the stored procedure? What is performance level of your SQL Azure database?

Comment: The app is running in an Azure Cloud Service and we get the same poor performance from their as I do from my local SQL Server query. The only time it's fast is when I run it from the Azure Portal  "Manage" window. The whole DB slowed down earlier this week. We upgraded to S2 to see if it would fix but it made NO difference - which is weird anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a new "Business" instance and move the database there. Performance returned to normal without any changes to the DB or associated app. Investigation showed that the S0/1/2 instances were all SLOWER than the "Business" instances (that are about to be retired by MS). We will be consulting them this week. It's probable that we need to pay for their Premium service to sustain the performance we get from the old Web/Business instances. This still does not account for WHY the original database slowed down, nor why performance would differ when accessed from the Azure console vs SQLIDE/Application.